# Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate values

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table (table1) with 3 categories/sub-categories columns, callIDs, client IDs, and a duration. Client IDs can be duplicates (they have different callIDs belonging to various sub categories).

I have another table (table2) with unique client IDs and a $amount.

I was hoping to use a with statement, with a table showing unique IDs and sum(duration) as Totalduration (from table 1).
And then select cat1, cat2, cat3, clientID, sum(duration), $amount*Totalduration/duration with an inner join of the two tables, group by 1,2,3,4

Basically that would do a pro-rata of the $amount based on the duration. But of course that doesn't work, cannot mix aggregate and non aggregate :(

Any tips/ideas on how to do that please?

Thanks

Edit:

Table 1:

```
Cat 1   Cat 2   Cat 3  CallID   Client ID  Duration
A       A       A      1        1          50
A       A       C      2        1          30
A       A       A      3        2          52
A       A       C      4        3          20
A       B       C      5        3          40
C       C       C      6        3          15
A       C       C      7        4          18
C       C       C      8        5          65
C       B       B      9        6          51
```

Table 2:

```
Client ID    Cost
1            150
2            190
3            130
4            120
5            140
6            190
```

And I'm trying to get this Result_table for each unique combination of the 3 Cats:

```
Cat 1   Cat 2   Cat 3  Total Duration  Blended Cost
A       A       A      ...             ...
A       A       C      ...             ...
A       B       C      ...             ...
C       C       C      ...             ...
A       C       C      ...             ...
C       C       C      ...             ...
C       B       B      ...             ...
```

Cost being blended pro-rata the duration for a unique Client ID. For example, client 1 has a duration of 50min ins A/A/A and 30min in A/A/C and a  cost of 150, in the Result_table we would add for line A/A/A 50min for Total Duration and 150*30/(30+50) Blended Cost. And then keep summing-up the following customers with the same logic.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, preferably in *text tables* in the question..

Comment: Your question does not show the desired result, with actual expected calculated results, based on the test data.  Notice, you have C, C, C twice in the result, yet you say: `I'm trying to get this Result_table for each unique combination of the 3 Cats`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I understand.  You are trying to spread the cost of the client over the categories and then summarize by category.  Window functions!

```
select cat1, cat2, cat3, sum(duration),
       sum(cost * duration * 1.0 / client_duration) as blended_cost
from (select t1.*, t2.cost,
             sum(t1.duration) over (partition by t1.clientid) as client_duration
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t1.clientid = t2.clientid
     ) t1
group by cat1, cat2, cat3;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! You are right, this is what I was looking for, apologies if original message wasn't clear I was probably too tired and should have waited this morning before posting.

I should probably find another training, I did my company's 2h sql tutorial and never heard of window functions... I got a feeling they left out a few other essential tools like these!!